# appending to an element only once

Tags: jquery

I want to append a menu on click. There are lots of results (class="worked_btn"), and I want to be able to click on any result and append this menu. I added the counter so that it will only show the menu once, but the problem is that if someone wants to click on another .worked_btn class, it will not show the menu, as the counter is no longer 0.

So how do you append something only once? I have also tried after and appento, prepend, etc, but still no luck. So how do I add this new ul element after the .worked_btn class element once.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
counter = 0; // used to make sure it only shows once
$('.worked_btn').click(function(){
    if(counter < 1) {
        $(this).append('<ul class="worked_menu"><li class="menu_send">Send Email</li><li class="menu_worked">Set as Worked</li><li class="menu_not">Set as Not Worked</li></ul>');
        counter++;
    }
});
});
```

UPDATE
We also want to be able to hide the menu as well, and have the ability to show it again. Like a toggle.

Comment: Do you mean that you want this code to only work once for each instance of a `.worked_btn` element, or once for *all* of those elements?

Comment: You append the menu on the first `click` but when you click again, you don't want to append it, you want to show it.  Is this correct?  (i.e. there is an `else` part of this `if` condition. Does that help?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/FRneS/

Comment: @Ani - Doesn't work in both places though: http://jsfiddle.net/FRneS/1/ (note that if you click here, or here will not function)

Comment: I don't want it to keep appending on click. In fact I would want it to hide if its clicked again. And then show if its clicked again after that.

Comment: do a toggle once counter is set to 1. How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/FRneS/2/

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/GJ4gA/)***

Just use a data attribute flag. This will allow you append the menu to any worked_btn element which has not yet been clicked while preventing any worked_btn element which has been clicked from generating the menu. In order to determine which was clicked and which menu to remove, this state needs a little bit of management as shown.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 $('.worked_btn').click(function(){
  if($(this).data('wasclicked')==undefined) {
   $('.worked_menu').parent().removeData('wasclicked');
   $('.worked_menu').remove();
   $(this).append('<ul class="worked_menu"><li class="menu_send">Send Email</li><li class="menu_worked">Set as Worked</li><li class="menu_not">Set as Not Worked</li></ul>')
     .data('wasclicked',true);
  }else{
   $(this).removeData('wasclicked');
   $('.worked_menu').remove();   
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: But I want them to be able to click it again if necessary once the menu hides again.

Comment: @user2909486 - After "click here" is clicked, you want the menu to hide if "or here" was clicked and then show the menu in the "or here" location?

Comment: @user2909486 - See edited fiddle and explanation please.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a counter, you can try add a new class to indicate if it has been clicked or not.

```
$('.worked_btn').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $('.worked_btn').removeClass('selected');
        $('ul.worked_menu').remove();
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).append('<ul class="worked_menu"><li class="menu_send">Send Email</li><li class="menu_worked">Set as Worked</li><li class="menu_not">Set as Not Worked</li></ul>');
    }
});
```

and clear the menu that is already displayed:

```
$('ul.worked_menu').remove();
```

EDIT: to remove it where clicking off anywhere in the document, just bind to the document a event handler:

```
$(document).click(function (event){
  if (!$(event.target).hasClass('worked_btn')) {
      $('.worked_btn').removeClass('selected');
      $('ul.worked_menu').remove();
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bPUWZ/

Comment: Great. What about removing the element, when clicking off it, anywhere in the document?

Comment: Oh, and I think you mean: if(!$(this).hasClass('selected'))

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have just updated my answer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your menu as a variable, you can reuse the menu object.

Also since append doesn't copy but actually moves the object to it's new location. This should do exactly what you need.

```
jQuery( function($) {
    var menu = $('<ul class="worked_menu"><li class="menu_send">Send Email</li><li class="menu_worked">Set as Worked</li><li class="menu_not">Set as Not Worked</li></ul>');
    $('.worked_btn').click( function() {
        $(this).append(menu);
    }
});
```